# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar un método de una clase de C# en un formulario de HTML?

Tags: c#, html

Tengo este código, el cual quiero que sea mandado a llamar al momento de hacer click al botón de submit en un formulario de html.

```
namespace IX_Registros.Handlers
{
    public class Eventos : IHttpHandler
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You will need to configure this handler in the Web.config file of your 
        /// web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
        /// see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
        /// </summary>
        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            // Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
            // Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //write your handler implementation here.
;

            string Tipo = context.Request.QueryString["Tipo"];

            switch (Tipo)
            {
                /*Pagina Index Portada Perfil -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
                case "IndexSelectPerfil":
                    {
                        RegistroEvento(context);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Y este es mi formulario de HTML

```
<form class="form-header" action="Eventos.ashx" role="form" method="POST" id="#">
                        <input type="hidden" name="u" value="503bdae81fde8612ff4944435">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="bfdba52708">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="NE" id="NombreEmpresa" type="text" placeholder="Nombre Empresa" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="NA" id="NombreAsistente" type="text" placeholder="Nombre Asistente" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="PU" id="Puesto" type="text" placeholder="Puesto" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="CO" id="Correo" type="email" placeholder="Correo" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" name="TE" id="Telefono" type="number" placeholder="Tel&eacute;fono" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group last">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg" value="Registrarse">
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Tengo entendido que debo de hacer cierta acción en el apartado de web.config, no sé si lo tenga de la forma correcta, pero tengo esto para mandarlo a llamar

```
<add verb="*" path="Eventos.ashx" validate="false" type="IX_Registros.Handlers.Eventos.RegistroEvento" />
```

También, al momento de cargar la página ingresando el URL http://localhost:49967/Eventos.ashx me aparece la página totalmente en blanco

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio 2015 Community y utilicé el Framework de Code On Time para generar el proyecto

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola es posible que te salga la página en blanco porque no estás escribiendo nada como respuesta. Prueba a hacer un `context.Response.Write("Evento registrado con éxito");` y comprueba las peticiones que se hacen a servidor con las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- Buen día, en primer lugar, hay que tener claro cuando se debe utilizar "Generic Handler".
Te recomiendo la siguiente pagina: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/warnov/2009/08/15/introduccin-a-generic-handlers-en-asp-net/

2.- También puedes utilizar para grabar información de tu formulario, por ejemplo desde AJAX:

```
<script>
// only for demo purposes
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Handler/Eventos.ashx",
            type: "GET",
            data: { NombreEmpresa: 'NombreEmpresa', NombreAsistente: 'NombreAsistente' },
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").validate();
});
```

3.- Cambios al formulario: id="form1", action="#".

Espero que te sea de tu utilidad.
Saludos